# Why is returning false with onSubmit reloading?

Tags: javascript, return, validation, reload

I know this probably staring me in the face but:

I have a basic for with a for header of:

```
<form onSubmit="return validateClinicalReports();" name="clinicalreport" method="post" action="process.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

the js looks at each input using: document.getElementById("name"). If it sees that the input is blank it colors the input yellow, selects it, and give is focus. Pretty simple, I use it on another form that has different inputs:

```
if(name == "")
    {
        document.getElementById("name").style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
        document.getElementById("name").select();
        document.getElementById("name").focus();
        return false;
    }
```

I literally copied that from another function (just changed the variable and id to name). When I submit I can see it take the blank input yellow, then it reloads the whole form. My other forms work fine with.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do not use "name" as a variable or id since window.name is an actual variable. Instead call it FirstName or such

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you shouldn't get in a hurry and use a preset keyword as you input id name :::headdeask:::

Answer (score 0):

The onSubmit handler calls validateClinicalReports() without any parameters.  You didn't include the complete function, but what is the "name" variable and where does it come from?

My guess is that the "if (name == "")" code is not getting executed at all.  You can verify that it is getting called by adding an alert() call as the first statement inside the if body.    You can probably just remove the if() test completely and always execute the code.

Also, if you are going to use getElementById(), you should add "id=name" to the form tag.

Comment: the validateClinicalReports doesn't need any parameters in this case. I don't need to pass anything to it since it pulls the variable value inside the if statement.

The name variable was just an example used in this question to as a placeholder for any variable.

I used "location" as a variable. I changed it to "loc" and it worked.